# Timestamp in file name JS

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I want to add a time stamp to a XML file while it's copy from location A to B.

```
const fs = require('fs');

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('\\\\IP\\FOLDER\\FILE.xml', 'c:\\FOLDER\\FILE.xml', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('OK! Copy FILE.xml');
});
```

The copy works, but I have no idea how to add the time stamp.

Comment: what do you mean "add a timestamp". Add it where? On the filename? Inside the file? Something else? Please be clear about your requirement. P.S. Is this NodeJS? Please tag it appropriately if so.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Date.now](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) gives you a time stamp (i.e. the number elapsed of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970).

You can add it to the second argument for `copyFile`, which is the destination path an file name.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('\\\\IP\\FOLDER\\FILE.xml', `c:\\FOLDER\\FILE_${Date.now()}.xml`, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('OK! Copy FILE.xml');
});
```

Note the back ticks – that's a JavaScript template string that allows you to add data using `${}`.

If you need a date string of the current day, as you pointed out in the comments, you can write a little helper function that creates this string:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function getDateString() {
  const date = new Date();
  const year = date.getFullYear();
  const month = `${date.getMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, '0');
  const day =`${date.getDate()}`.padStart(2, '0');
  return `${year}${month}${day}`
}

// destination.txt will be created or overwritten by default.
fs.copyFile('\\\\IP\\FOLDER\\FILE.xml', `c:\\FOLDER\\FILE_${getDateString()}.xml`, (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('OK! Copy FILE.xml');
});
```

This will create a file name like this: *FILE_20182809.xml*

Comment: Cool it works! Is there a option to display the date without time?

Comment: Sure, take a look at the documentation of the date API, there are many options available to format a date: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: `Date.now()` is the simplest way to get a timestamp, I used that in my answer because you didn't specify how exactly you want the timestamp

Comment: I can't figured out, could please help me? so: FILE_YYYMMDD.XML